# Adding form rows into the angular table form with a loop

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

I want to add a for loop to the Angular form for each tax_rate_details array, so that the form text boxes are automatically populated with the data values. I want to addNewRow for every tax_rate_details array. What changes should I make in my HTML or TypeScript file to accomplish this?

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/purushottamnawale/Tax-Authority-CRUD)

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSlideToggleChange } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TaxRateService, TaxService } from 'src/app/app.service';
import { Country, Tax } from 'src/app/Tax';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-tax-rate',
  templateUrl: './update-tax-rate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-tax-rate.component.css']
})
export class UpdateTaxRateComponent {
  data: any;
  taxrate: any;
  TaxAuthorityList: any;
  TaxRateList: any;
  TaxRateForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private taxRateService: TaxRateService, private taxService: TaxService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.TaxRateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      tax_rate_name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      tax_authority_ref_id: [''],
      tax_type_ref_id: [''],
      is_active: [true],
      tax_rate_details: this.formBuilder.array([this.tax_rate_details()])
    });
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let pk = this.route.snapshot.params['pk'];
    this.taxRateService.getTaxRate(pk).subscribe(data => {
      this.taxrate = data
      console.log(this.taxrate)
      this.populateForm();
    })
    this.refreshList();
  }

  refreshList() {
    this.taxService.getTaxes().subscribe((data) => {
      // console.log(data);
      this.TaxAuthorityList = data;
      this.TaxAuthorityList.forEach((tax: Tax) => {
        // console.log(tax.pk, tax.name);
      });
    });
  }

  get formDetails() {
    return this.TaxRateForm.get('tax_rate_details') as FormArray;
  }
  addNewRow() {
    this.formDetails.push(this.tax_rate_details());
  }

  deleteRow(index: number) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      this.formDetails.removeAt(index);
      return true;
    }
  }

  tax_rate_details() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      hsn_sac_no: ['', [Validators.required]],
      description: [''],
      from_date: [''],
      to_date: [''],
      tax_rate: [''],
      rcm_flag: [true],
      cess: [''],
    });
  }

  populateForm(): void {
    this.TaxRateForm.patchValue({
      tax_rate_name: this.taxrate.tax_rate_name,
      tax_authority_ref_id: this.taxrate.tax_authority_ref_id,
      tax_type_ref_id: this.taxrate.tax_type_ref_id,
      is_active:this.taxrate.is_active,
      tax_rate_details: this.formBuilder.array([this.tax_rate_details()])
    });
  }

  submit() {
    this.data = this.TaxRateForm.value
    this.taxrate.tax_rate_name = this.data.tax_rate_name
    this.taxrate.tax_authority_ref_id = this.data.tax_authority_ref_id
    this.taxrate.is_active = this.data.is_active
    this.taxrate.tax_rate_details= this.formBuilder.array([this.tax_rate_details()])

    // console.log(this.data)

    this.taxRateService.updateTaxRate(this.taxrate?.pk, this.taxrate).subscribe(data => {
      // console.log(data)
    })

    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }
  public useDefault1 = false;
  public toggle1(event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    console.log('toggle', event.checked);
    this.useDefault1 = event.checked;
    this.TaxRateForm.patchValue({
      is_active: event.checked ? true : false,
    });
  }

  public useDefault2 = false;
  public toggle2(event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    console.log('toggle', event.checked);
    this.useDefault2 = event.checked;
    this.tax_rate_details().patchValue({
      rcm_flag: event.checked ? true : false
    });
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add Tax Rate</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Navbar consists only Home and Add Tax-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" routerLink="/">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/add">Add Tax Rate</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Form -->
    <div class="my-5">
        <div class="mx-5 mr-5">
            <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
                <h2 class="text-left d-inline" id="tax_authority">Tax Rate</h2>
                <button class="btn btn-primary d-inline" routerLink="/viewtaxrate"><i class="fa-solid fa-calendar"></i> List of Tax
                    Authority</button>
            </div>

            <form [formGroup]="TaxRateForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" class="mx-5 mr-5 my-5">
                <!--Tax Rate Name-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col form-group">
                        <label for="tax_rate_name" class="form-label required" id="tax_rate_name">Tax rate name</label>
                        <input formControlName="tax_rate_name" value={{taxrate?.tax_rate_name}} type="text" name="tax_rate_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Tax Rate Name">
                    </div>

                    <!-- Tax Authority -->
                    <div class="col form-group">
                        <label for="tax_authority_ref_id" class="form-label required">Tax authority</label>
                        <select class="form-select" data-style="btn-primary" formControlName="tax_authority_ref_id" name="tax_authority_ref_id" id="tax_authority_ref_id">
                            <option [value]="taxauthority.pk" *ngFor="let taxauthority of TaxAuthorityList">
                                {{taxauthority.name}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Tax Type -->
                    <div class="col form-group">
                        <label for="tax_type_ref_id" class="form-label required">Tax type</label>
                        <select class="form-select" value={{taxrate?.tax_authority_ref_id}} data-style="btn-primary" formControlName="tax_type_ref_id" name="tax_type_ref_id" id="tax_type_ref_id">
                            <option value="GST">GST</option>
                            <option value="Income Tax">Income Tax</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row my-5">
                    <!--Status-->
                    <div class="col form-group">
                        <label for="is_active" class="row form-label" id="is_active_label">Status</label>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="is_active" id="active">Inactive</label>
                            <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="TaxRateForm.get('is_active')!.value" (change)="toggle1($event)" id="mat-slider"></mat-slide-toggle>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="is_active" id="inactive">Active</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col my-3" formArrayName="tax_rate_details">
                    <h2 class="define_tax_rate_details">Define Tax Rate Details</h2>
                    <table class="table  table-bordered my-3">
                        <thead class="smaller-font">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Action</th>
                                <th scope="col">Hsn sac no</th>
                                <th scope="col">Description</th>
                                <th scope="col">From date</th>
                                <th scope="col">To date</th>
                                <th scope="col">Tax Rate</th>
                                <th scope="col">RCM flag</th>
                                <th scope="col">Cess</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let dynamic of formDetails.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                                <td>
                                    <div class="my-3">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" *ngIf="i==0" (click)="addNewRow()"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-plus" style="color: #b95bf2;"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" *ngIf="i>0"><i class="fa-solid fa-square-minus" style="color: #f11616;"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col form-group my-4">
                                        <input formControlName="hsn_sac_no" value={{taxrate?.tax_rate_details[i]?.hsn_sac_no}} type="text" name="hsn_sac_no" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Hsn sac no">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col form-group my-4">
                                        <input formControlName="description" value={{taxrate?.tax_rate_details[i]?.description}} type="text" name="description" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="description">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col form-group my-4">
                                        <input formControlName="from_date" value={{taxrate?.tax_rate_details[i]?.from_date}} type="date" name="from_date" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="From Date">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col form-group my-4">
                                        <input formControlName="to_date" value={{taxrate?.tax_rate_details[i]?.to_date}} type="date" name="to_date" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="To Date">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col form-group my-4">
                                        <input formControlName="tax_rate" value={{taxrate?.tax_rate_details[i]?.tax_rate}} type="number" name="tax_rate" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Tax Rate">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col form-group my-4">
                                        <label class="form-check-label form-control-sm" for="rcm_flag" id="active_tax_details">Inactive</label>
                                        <!-- <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="taxRateDetailsForm.get('rcm_flag')!.value" (change)="toggle2($event)" class="smaller-slide-toggle" id="mat-slider"></mat-slide-toggle> -->
                                        <!-- <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="group.get('rcm_flag')!.value" (change)="toggle2($event)" class="smaller-slide-toggle" id="mat-slider"></mat-slide-toggle> -->
                                        <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="rcm_flag" (change)="toggle2($event)" class="smaller-slide-toggle" id="mat-slider"></mat-slide-toggle>
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="rcm_flag" id="inactive_tax_details">Active</label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col form-group my-4">
                                        <input formControlName="cess" value={{taxrate?.tax_rate_details[i]?.cess}} type="number" name="cess" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Cess">
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col form-group d-flex justify-content-center my-3">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
                        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary mx-2 mr-2">
                        <button type="back" class="btn btn-danger" routerLink="/viewtaxrate">Back</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit: I have found a solution to my problem. The implementation can be found on GitHub [Repository](https://github.com/purushottamnawale/Tax-Authority-CRUD).**

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question that has already been solved, but I have created a node package for an inline table form component that is generic as possible for re-usability for anyone that stumbles upon this in future.
A map of column headers and their validator functions are passed as an input, and optionally an array of objects can also be passed as input where each object in the list will be mapped to a row in the table.

Create, update, and delete events are emitted from component so it can be reacted to in your angular app any way you see fit. Feel free to check it out.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-table-form

Install the package using this command:

```
npm install ng-table-form
```